# How to get the internal table data in excel format if the report runs in background?

Tags: excel, abap, jobs, internal-tables

Could you please tell me the way to get internal table data in excel file to be saved in local desktop (presentation server). Remember that the report runs in background.

Comment: Theoretically you could achieve smth similar to your requirement by creating custom report which results would be sent to Email using background job.

Answer (score 2):

Both requirements a contradictionary because a backround job does not have any connection to any SAPGui. I.e. there is no SAPGui connection linked to a background job ans thus it is not possible to determine onto which local desktop the excel file should be saved.

A possibility would be to store the results that are created in the backround job somehow and externalize the save to a local desktop into another program. When creating files on the SAP AS you should keep in mind what happens with these file after they are not needed any longer. I.e. you need to do the file maintenance (deletion of files after they are not needed any longer) your self.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do this, if you create the file on a SAP AS and move this file using any shell file move command. However, it's a bad practice to make any connection from SAP AS to a user's machine.

The best solution here is to create the file on SAP AS. The user must download the file manually from the SAP AS. You can also send this file to a user for example per e-mail. The user will do no manual work in the last case.

Also a good practice is to use PI server functionality. It can deliver your file within a way the user wants to have.